# Rails, RSpec and Webrat: Expected output matches rendered output but still getting error in view spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webrat

I've just gotten started using BDD with RSpec/Cucumber/Webrat and Rails and I've run into some frustration trying to get my view spec to pass.

First of all, I am running Ruby 1.9.1p129 with Rails 2.3.2, RSpec and RSpec-Rails 1.2.6, Cucumber 0.3.11, and Webrat 0.4.4.

Here is the code relevant to my question

*config/routes.rb:*

```
map.b_posts                  'backend/posts',
                             :controller => 'backend/posts',
                             :action => 'backend_index',
                             :conditions => { :method => :get }

map.connect                  'backend/posts',
                             :controller => 'backend/posts',
                             :action => 'create',
                             :conditions => { :method => :post }
```

*views/backend/posts/create.html.erb:*

```
<% form_tag do %>
<% end %>
```

*spec/views/backend/posts/create.html.erb_spec.rb:*

```
describe "backend/posts/create.html.erb" do  
  it "should render a form to create a post" do
    render "backend/posts/create.html.erb"
    response.should have_selector("form", :method => 'post', :action => b_posts_path) do |form|
      # Nothing here yet.
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the relevant part of the output when I run script/spec:

```
'backend/posts/create.html.erb should render a form to create a post' FAILED
expected following output to contain a <form method='post' action='/backend/posts'/> tag:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><form action="/backend/posts" method="post">
</form></body></html>
```

It would appear to me that what have_selector is looking for is exactly what the template generates, yet the example still fails. I am very much looking forward to seeing my error (because I have a feeling it is *my* error). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Update: It works if I remove the block.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the block try using rspec-rails matchers instead of the webrat matchers.

```
describe "backend/posts/create.html.erb" do  
  it "should render a form to create a post" do
    render "backend/posts/create.html.erb"
    response.should have_tag("form[method=post][action=?]", b_posts_path) do |form|
      with_tag('input')
      # ... etc
    end
  end
end
```