# Rails webrat gem - render method missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd, webrat

I am using rspec and webrat for behavior driven development. This is the first time I am using webrat.

I followed webrat's [instructions](https://github.com/brynary/webrat/tree/v0.7.3) on how to use the gem, so I think it is installed correctly (the gem shows when I use `bundle show`).

The problem occurs when I just want to test whether my rendered view (welcome/index.html.erb) has an h1 tag. Should be fairly simple.

My code looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "welcome/index.html.erb" do
  render :template => "welcome/index", :layout => "layouts/application"

  it "displays a welcome message" do
    rendered.should have_selector "h1"
  end
end
```

I got there because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025036/rails-rspec-and-webrat-expected-output-matches-rendered-output-but-still-getti), but maybe it is a little old. When I run the test it gives me

```
undefined method `render'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to solve it. Apparently this is much easier than I thought:

```
describe "welcome/index.html.erb" do
  it "displays a welcome message" do
    render
    rendered.should have_selector "h1"
  end
end
```

Apparently I just have to say `render` *inside* the "it" block. This solves the problem for me.